# IBM Advanced Find JSONStore saying "INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD" when the advanced query exceeds 999 records

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore, mobilefirst-cli

***VERSION OF MFP JSONSTORE PLUGIN: 8.0.2017033009***

Hi I have a JSONStore with 2000 records and want to filter out only 1217 records from them which are similar to one property.

So i used  `WL.JSONStore.QueryPart().inside('PROPERTY', [...PROPERTYVALUEARRAY]);`

Everything works fine till PROPERTYVALUEARRAY is limited to 999 records but when it exceeds/touches 1000 we are doomed the JSONstore API as below started returning the error as in picture.

`WL.JSONStore.get("JSONSTORENAME").advancedFind([query]).then(res => { console.log(res)}).fail(res => { console.log(res)});`

[image]

Comment: Can you try with latest cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore  version ?retrieving huge data is fixed in latest version.

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar can you please give me the exact version number please and also the other dependent version it required. we are having a run time build so dont want to give the latest since it will get the latest plugin everytime.

Comment: Just run command:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore 
It will add latest.

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore@8.0.2018040508.The version 8.0.2018040508 is the latest .

Comment: You can try any of these version which has large data fix 
["8.0.2017070506","8.0.2017071209","8.0.2017081712","8.0.2017082110","8.0.2017090705","8.0.2018021611","8.0.2018040508"]

Comment: Let me know if it works I will add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving huge/large  JSONStore data has been fixed in latest ifix releases .

Use ifix version later than iFix 8.0.0.0-MFPF-IF20170705-1849.

For more details about iFix release see here :
[MobileFirst Foundation iFix 8.0.0.0-MFPF-IF20170705-1849 released](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/07/06/8-0-ifix-release/)